# J2ME Displaying Content

Tags: java, text, java-me

I am using j2me to develop a mobile application. The application displays some information which is just some text depending on the user's choice. What is the best way of displaying such a text? The text should also be formatted(like bolding some text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) , It supports HTML to be rendered also , so you will have your your issue solved nicely.

Or if you want to continue with lcdui.
[Here is a sample code for you](http://www.java-samples.com/j2me/change-fontsize-and-color-free-j2me-sample-program.htm)

Comment: should I have to go for a new framework? is there no other option to display what I want?

Comment: @Nave , It seems you are using lcdui.

Comment: @Nave , You can you `StringItem` and your custom font to display **bold** text